# how and what to log in MVC application with global action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext, action-filter

I'm more familiar with the WebApi pipeline, and there is a convenient method whereby I can read and write the the HttpRequest / Response as a string. Easy.

For MVC, it doesn't seem right to log the entire "filter context"... so my question is (1) what do you think are the relevant fields I should log (I'm not that familiar with it at the moment), and (2) how best should I convert these fields to string? xml serialization, json serialization? string builder/stream writer?

Here's my current code that is pretty skinny:

My Web Api:

```
            var requestMessage = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _logService.WriteInfo(requestMessage);

            var responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _logService.WriteInfo(responseMessage));
```

For MVC:

```
    private void LogRequestInfo(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
        var parameters = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters().ToString(); // TODO: need to serialize this

        string logTemplate = "Request: controller: {0}, action:{1}, url:{2}, parameters:{3}";
        string message = string.Format(logTemplate, controllerName, actionName, url, parameters);
        _logService.WriteInfo(message);
    }
    private void LogResponseInfo(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string logTemplate = "Response: {0}";
        string message = string.Format(logTemplate, filterContext.Result); // TODO: need way to serialize the relevant action result
        _logService.WriteInfo(message);
    }
```